# Unable to delete file C:\Users\Master\Documents\NetBeansProjects\repeat\build\web\WEB-INF\lib\primefaces-5.0.jar BUILD FAILED

Tags: java, primefaces

I have created a java application so when I tell my class main:

package javaapplication4;

public class JavaApplication4 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

}

It should write "Hello World" on the console... But after I do Run Main Project(F6) before I can see "Hello World" in the console it takes me to the web with the next

[image]

I can just close it and continue working but it should not be that way

If I do - Clean and Build Main Project (Mayús+F11) - it gives me the next on the console

[image]

I have tried just going and deleting the primefaces.jar manually but when I do run(F6) again it creates again the primefaces.jar in the same place.

[image]

I would be very grateful if you can help me to fix this.

Comment: your project is more than just a simple "hello world" program. It's kindof a web application. Probably you followed this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/netbeans.html) 

Maybe try to recreate the project. Regarding the "unable to delete" message. If you have the folder open in windows explorer it keeps a file handle which will disallow netbeans to delete the file.

Comment: @luckyluke Thanks for the attempt. It was not a web application but a Java With Ant - Java Application. It seems the folder repeat had been created automatically. I just delete that folder and now Netbeans is working well.